# Chess Board (5×5) problem

Tags: combinatorics

> 25 small squares of a 5×5 chess board are coloured with 5 different
>   colours available, such that each row contains all 5 available colours
>   and no two adjacent squares have same colour. Then the no. of
>   different arrangements possible are?

My attempt:

Let the colours be R,B,G,W,V

To fill the first row I have 5×4×3×2×1

Now for the second row I am sort of messing up I am able to determine 4 cases only but I am getting it at all messed up again and again.

Help me with the editing as well please.

Comment: Each row is a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of the previous row. There are $44$ derangements of 5 items. If you think of it as a permutation of the row, the only kinds of permutation of 5 items where everything moves are a 5-cycle (there are $4!$ of those) or a 2-cycle combined with a 3-cycle (there are $\binom{5}{2} * 2$ of those).

Comment: Thank you that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following chess table:
$$\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline  \end{array}$$

Let's fill the first row with any colors:

$$\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline a& b& c& d& e \\ \hline  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline  \end{array}$$

The ways to choose $(a,b,c,d,e)$ is $5!$

For the second row, apply inclusion-exclusion.

$$\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline a& b& c& d&e \\ \hline a'&b'  &c'  &d'  &e'  \\ \hline  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline  \end{array}$$

Total possible concievable arrangements of $(a',b',c',d',e')$ are again $5!$ but we must remove some unfavorable cases.

This is known as a *derangement*. So, we have counted in our $5!$ some cases where one of $l = l'$ where $l$ is one of ${a,b,c,d,e}$. The number of such cases is $\binom 514!$. But, in this, we have removed some cases where $l=l'$ for two $l$ twice (once for one $l$, another time for the other). The number of such cases is $\binom 523!$. Continuing like this, we have the total good arrangements as $5!\left(\displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^5\left(-1\right)^k\frac 1{k!}\right)$. Once we have set the arrangement for this row, we may repeat the process for the next row, and so on. 
$$\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline a& b& c& d&e \\ \hline a'&b'  &c'  &d'  &e'  \\ \hline  a''&b''  &c''  &d''  &e''  \\ \hline  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline  \end{array}$$

So, by my calculation, the total favorable arrangements is $$5!^5\left(\displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^5\left(-1\right)^k\frac 1{k!}\right)^4$$ 
$$= 120*44^4\boxed{=449771520}$$

Comment: Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: @DareDevil Cheers, glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

As you noticed for the first we have $5!$ arrangement, for the second row we can use [**inclusion and exclusion principle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) as follows.

Notably, the number of cases for the second row with at least two adjacent squares with the same colour with respect to the first row, by inclusion and exclusion principle, is:

$$5\cdot 4!-\binom{5}{2}\cdot 3!+\binom{5}{3}\cdot 2!-\binom{5}{4}\cdot 1!+\binom{5}{5}\cdot 0!=76$$

therefore the number of cases for the second row with no adjacent squares with the same colour with respect to the first row is:

$$5!-76=120-76=44$$

which is valid for all the others three rows and then finally, by multiplication rule, we obtain:

$$5!\cdot (44)^4$$

Comment: Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: @DareDevil You are welcome! Bye